# How to draw dotted line between axis on Bar graph android

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am using achartengine jar for Bar graph view. My requirement of Bar Graph design example diagram has attached below.

[image]

- The top Image is My requiremnt bar graph
- The Bottom Image is my output image.

My code is:

```
public class TestClass  extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GraphicalView BarChartView;

    @SuppressLint("ParserError")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph);
        if (BarChartView==null )
        {

            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer();
            setChartSettings(renderer);
            BarChartView  = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, getBarDataset(), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
            LinearLayout playout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph2);
            playout.addView(BarChartView);

        } else
        {
            BarChartView.repaint();
            BarChartView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer)
    {
        renderer.setYTitle("Hits");
        renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(7);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(100);

    }
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getBarDataset()
    {
        XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("A");
        XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("B");
        XYSeries series3 = new XYSeries("C");
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        series1.add(3, 50);
        dataset.addSeries(series1);

        series2.add(4, 25);
        dataset.addSeries(series2);

        series3.add(5, 100);
        dataset.addSeries(series3);

        return dataset;

    }
    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer() {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mrenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        //double[] range = {5,5,0};

        mrenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        mrenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        mrenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        mrenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        mrenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
        mrenderer.setXLabels(0);
        mrenderer.addXTextLabel(0, "SAVINGS TOTAL");
        mrenderer.addXTextLabel(1.5, "SPEND BREAKDOWN");
        mrenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "DEPT");
        mrenderer.setMargins(new int[]{20, 30, 15, 0});
        mrenderer.setAxesColor(Color.WHITE);
        mrenderer.setChartTitle("");
        mrenderer.setXTitle("");
       // mrenderer.setInitialRange(range, 1);
        mrenderer.setBarWidth(100);

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer2.setColor(Color.RED);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer3.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer3);

        return mrenderer;

    }


}
```

Kindly Please help me solve the Bar Grapg dotted line between x and Y axis.
If any one have idea please le me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
renderer.setStroke(BasicStroke.DASHED);
```

or

```
renderer.setStroke(BasicStroke.DOTTED);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Harin.. It's not working harin..could you please tell me where should i add this stroke in my code. @Harin Kaklotar

Comment: The below code is working fine for me.
renderer.setShowGrid(true);    
renderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);